# Why does this scrape return undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

When I run this code I get undefined but it is clear that the ski and product_id are in the value form.

I want:

> value="BTdtb4CBz3uSJ2qv"
>
> value="adi-ss20-042"

but I get "undefined"

```
class TresBien {
      async scrapeRaffleInfo() {
        // scrape the form_key and sku values
        const response = await axios(
          "https://tres-bien.com/adidas-yeezy-boost-380-mist-fx9764-ss20"
        );
        console.log("response: ", response);
        const html = await response.data;
    
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const res = $('input[name="sku"]').val();
        const ans = $('input[name="form_key"]').val();
        console.log(res && ans);
      }
    }
    
    const main = async () => {
      const tb = new TresBien(
        "https://tres-bien.com/adidas-yeezy-700-v3-alvah-h67799-ss20"
      );
      let checkoutSucc = await tb.scrapeRaffleInfo();
      if (checkoutSucc) {
        Logger.logEventSuccess("Raffle successfully entered");
      }
    };
    
    main();
```

Comment: The `scrapeRaffleInfo()` function does not `return` anything.

Comment: @Pointy it has console.log which logs undefined

Comment: Probably the  product the url references is no longer available. The input named `"sku"` is available for the following url: [https://tres-bien.com/adidas-yeezy-700-v3-alvah-h67799-ss20](https://tres-bien.com/adidas-yeezy-700-v3-alvah-h67799-ss20). You do not use the url passed to the `TresBien` constructor in `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong in your code:

1. as @Pointy mentioned, `scrapeRaffleInfo()` is returning undefined and you're trying to use it in `checkoutSucc`
2. Tresbien class doesn't offer any constructor, yet you're passing your url as a parameter to the constructor of that class.
3. You're not using any of `axios` library methods (like: `get()`, `post()`, `put()`, `delete()`). typically you need `axios.get()` but there in your code, you're just using `axios()`